# Haskell: random number - Int of IO action

Tags: haskell, random, io, functional-programming, monads

I recently picked up Haskell and the syntax is really confusing to me. I am trying to get a random number between 0 and 51 using:

```
randomRIO (0, 51)
```

But I don't know how to make this an actual `Int` (instead of `IO Int`).

I believe you are supposed to be able to do:

```
gen <- randomRIO (0, 51)
```

and then `gen` is supposed to be an `Int`, but I have to do this in a `do`-block - how do I create the function that takes this and returns an `Int`?

From googling I'm afraid that there is something basic that I do not understand. I am completely lost.

Comment: The next line in the `do` block could be something like `print (yourFunc gen)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yep, there is something basic, and it's the most common thing new Haskellers struggle with.  Basically, everything you said is right, and if you want a "function" that returns a random int, you can't have it.

You can do

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    num <- getRandomR (0, 51)
    putStrLn ("The number is " ++ show num)
```

You can also factor it out

```
getCardIndex :: IO Int
getCardIndex = do
    ix <- getRandomR (0,51)
    return (ix + 1)   -- just as an example of how you can transform it

main :: IO ()
main = do
    card <- getCardIndex
    putStrLn ("The number is " ++ show card)
```

The thing you can't do is make it a pure function/value:

```
pureCardIndex :: Int
pureCardIndex = ioToPure (getRandomR (0,51)) -- NOT POSSIBLE
```

because there is no (ethical) function like `ioToPure`.  A pure function must always return the same output for the same input, which is precisely *not* what you want a random number function to do.  So we have to use `IO` with it.   Once you use `IO` to generate something random, anything that depends on that random number must also be in `IO`.

People will be quick to start explaining the theory of monads and all that, and it's good stuff, I just recommend approaching it patiently, getting used to these patterns before diving into the theoretical side.

Comment: How about `unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a` in this particular case? Isn't pseudo random number generation a less harmful effect, because it actually produces a return value and the calling side expects this very effect?

Comment: @ftor this is not an appropriate use of `unsafePerformIO`, and I think most of the community will agree with me.  When we're working in haskell, the *first* thing we expect of any function is referential transparency, which is what gives us that beloved freedom to equationally reason and refactor without thinking very hard.  `unsafePerformIO` is appropriate when the violation of r.t. is re-encapsulated, so that the interface remains pure.

Comment: @ftor `unsafePerformIO` is for situations when you have a pure function but aren't capable of proving it to the type system.  A good example would be FFI when calling a function that you know is pure.  Random number generation is absolutely effectful so should done within `IO`.

Comment: OK, there is no escape from mathematical rules. This is the first dogmatism I have encountered so far, which probably achieves something good :D

Comment: @ftor It's not dogmatism in this case; Doing it otherwise would just straight up break the semantics of the language and lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: @ftor In a purely functional programming language, if `rand :: Integer -> Integer`, the compiler is entitled to inline `let x = rand 6 in x + x` as `rand 6 + rand 6`. That is not a sound rewriting if `rand 6` is the result of a die: the former is never 7, for instance. Debugging this issue can easily drive one insane, since the issue is not in the code, but is introduced by the compiler. The compiler here is not at fault, since it relied on the lie `rand :: Integer -> Integer` which was guaranteed by the programmer -- which is the real issue.

Comment: Wonderful example, @chi. The compiler itself does equational reasoning and this only works with referential transparency. I should have considered that.